# Autopimport in the Monorepo project of PNPM

Tags: vue.js, vite, pnpm

#### Describe the bug

project: https://github.com/toimc/autoimport-monorepo-demo

I have written a very basic example of Monorepo in PNPM.

```
.
├── package.json
├── packages
│   ├── components
│   │   ├── README.md
│   │   ├── dist
│   │   │   ├── favicon.ico
│   │   │   ├── style.css
│   │   │   ├── vue-components.d.ts
│   │   │   ├── vue-components.es.js
│   │   │   ├── vue-components.es.js.map
│   │   │   ├── vue-components.umd.js
│   │   │   └── vue-components.umd.js.map
│   │   ├── env.d.ts
│   │   ├── package.json
│   │   ├── pnpm-lock.yaml
│   │   ├── public
│   │   │   └── favicon.ico
│   │   ├── src
│   │   │   ├── components
│   │   │   │   └── HelloWorld.vue
│   │   │   ├── main.ts
│   │   │   └── vite.ts
│   │   ├── tsconfig.app.json
│   │   ├── tsconfig.app.tsbuildinfo
│   │   ├── tsconfig.json
│   │   ├── tsconfig.node.json
│   │   ├── tsconfig.vitest.json
│   │   ├── vite.config.ts
│   │   └── vitest.config.ts
│   └── vue-template
│       ├── README.md
│       ├── auto-imports.d.ts
│       ├── index.html
│       ├── package.json
│       ├── public
│       │   └── vite.svg
│       ├── src
│       │   ├── App.vue
│       │   ├── assets
│       │   │   └── vue.svg
│       │   ├── components
│       │   │   └── HelloWorld.vue
│       │   ├── main.ts
│       │   ├── style.css
│       │   └── vite-env.d.ts
│       ├── tsconfig.json
│       ├── tsconfig.node.json
│       └── vite.config.ts
├── pnpm-lock.yaml
├── pnpm-workspace.yaml
└── yarn.lock
```

Vue template is a basic vite+Vue project, while components is a component library that exports Vue components and `getSum` function methods, with vite config:

```
    AutoImport({
      include: [
        /\.[tj]sx?$/, // .ts, .tsx, .js, .jsx
        /\.vue$/,
        /\.vue\?vue/, // .vue
        /\.md$/, // .md
      ],
      ignore: ['h'],
      imports: [
        'vue',
        {
          'vue-components': ['getSum'],
        },
      ],
      vueTemplate: true,
    }),
```

I want to use autoimport to automatically import the getSum method. I have configured it according to the official documentation, but the following error may occur when using pnpm monorepo：

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "vue-components" from "../components/dist/vue-components.es.js". Does the file exist?
/Users/toimc/Downloads/temp-mono/packages/components/dist/vue-components.es.js:3:25
1  |  import { defineComponent as l, openBlock as a, createElementBlock as p, createElementVNode as t, toDisplayString as _, pushScopeId as d, popScopeId as u, createTextVNode as r } from "vue";
2  |  
3  |  import { getSum } from 'vue-components';
   |                          ^
4  |  const i = (e) => (d("data-v-7ebc02a5"), e = e(), u(), e), h = { class: "greetings" }, g = { class: "green" }, m = /* @__PURE__ */ i(() => /* @__PURE__ */ t("h3", null, [
5  |    /* @__PURE__ */ r(" You’ve successfully created a project with "),
```

But I exported this file correctly because I tried to directly export the node_ The directory in modules does not use the pnpm soft chain method, but directly creates a new folder, which can be started with the vite debugging command normally without reporting the above error.

The same code, only modified to Yarn to manage Mono's workspace, had no problem and ran directly.

code: https://github.com/toimc/autoimport-monorepo-demo/blob/yarn/packages/vue-template/package.json

#### Reproduction

https://github.com/toimc/autoimport-monorepo-demo

#### System Info

```
System:
    OS: macOS 14.2.1
    CPU: (10) arm64 Apple M1 Max
    Memory: 1.29 GB / 64.00 GB
    Shell: 5.9 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.19.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.19.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.21 - /opt/homebrew/bin/yarn
    npm: 10.2.3 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.19.0/bin/npm
    pnpm: 8.12.1 - /opt/homebrew/bin/pnpm
  Browsers:
    Chrome: 120.0.6099.199
    Edge: 120.0.2210.121
    Safari: 17.2.1
```

#### Used Package Manager

pnpm

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of practice, I have found that only the corresponding dependencies need to be installed in the root directory, using `pnpm add xxxx -w`, which represents the packages that you need to reference each other in the current monorepo